# Mqtt Client in Java EE application under JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, mqtt, jca

I've developed a test Java EE application to send and receive messages through the MQTT protocol (tcp connection).
Under JBoss 7.1 I got a @Singleton @Startup that instantiates an Eclipse Paho client and a callback class.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class PahoClient implements PahoClientLocal {

@EJB
VehicleStatusLocal vehicleS;

private MqttClient client;
SubscribeCallback callback;
private List<String> logStat = new ArrayList<String>();



@PostConstruct
public void start() throws MqttException {
    try {
        System.out.println("NM info: STARTING MQTT CLIENT");
            client = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost", "NetworkManager", new MemoryPersistence());

        //CLIENT CONNECTION OPTIONS
        ...
        client.connect(mqttConnectOptions);

        //MESSAGE LISTENER
        callback = new SubscribeCallback(this, NM_STATUS_TOPIC, NM_ALARM_TOPIC);
        client.setCallback(callback);

        //TOPIC SUBSCRIBE
        ...
        } catch (MqttException e) {
        .....
}
public void sendMessage(String message) throws MqttPersistenceException, MqttException{
    this.client.publish(DEVICE_STATUS_TOPIC, message.getBytes(), 2, false);
} 
//
@Asynchronous
public void update(String matricola, String status, String latitude, String longitude, String  battery){
    vehicleS.updateVehicle(matricola, status, Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude), Integer.parseInt(battery));
}
```

I want to update received values to another bean. But in my Callback class i cannot inject any EJB (it breaks tcp connection) so i get the PahoClient instance in this way as you can see above:

```
callback = new SubscribeCallback(this, NM_STATUS_TOPIC, NM_ALARM_TOPIC)
```

So when i receive a message on my callback method i update values in this way
    public class SubscribeCallback implements MqttCallback{

```
public SubscribeCallback(PahoClient pahoClient, String topicNM, String topicALARM) {
    this.client=pahoClient;
    this.NM_STATUS_TOPIC = topicNM;
    this.NM_ALARM_TOPIC = topicALARM;
}
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception{
..
pahoClient.update(msg);
```

It seems to work fine. But in the console I see the MQTT thread updating the message, not the EJB. And I don't know if with a lot connections this works.
Any suggestion?

I was thinking about developing a JCA Adapter for my MQTT Client and my Java EE application, but I don't know if it's the right way.